# Python3, Scrape returned []

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have a python script for the scraping site, I need to scrape a few info(name, price, links, ID) this info will be put in MongoDB. But I have a problem with my scraping function. It returns to me a blank list.

Can you help me please with this?
Sorry for my English and thank you in advance

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pymongo
import difflib
import functools

URL = 'https://www.nickollsandperks.co.uk/New-and-Special-Offers/New-Whisky?order=relevance:asc'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


def newScrapItems():
    # global productNames,Names, links, Price, products_info_final
    content3 = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(content3.text, 'html.parser')
    itemList = []


    for products in soup3.find_all("div", {"class": 'facets-facet-browse-items'}):
        for products_info in products.find_all("div", {"class": "facets-items-collection-view-row"}):
            for products_info_final in products_info.find_all("div", {"class": "facets-item-cell-list"}):
                for generalInfo in products_info_final.find_all("div", {"class": "facets-item-cell-list-right"}):
                    for links in generalInfo.find_all("meta"):
                        for itemNamesNext in products_info.find_all("div", {"class": "item-title-description"}):
                            for prePrice in generalInfo.find_all("div", {"class": "item-button"}):
                                for Names in itemNamesNext.find_all("span"):
                                    for priceInfo in prePrice.find_all("div", {"class": "ProductViewsPrice.Price"}):
                                        for Price in priceInfo.find_all("span", {"class": "product-views-price-lead"}):
                                            productNames = {}

                                            productNames['price'] = Price.get_text()
                                            productNames['name'] = Names.get_text()
                                            productNames['link'] = links['content']
                                            productNames['ID'] = products_info_final['data-item-id']
                                            itemList.append(productNames)


    return itemList
newItems = newScrapItems()
print(newScrapItems())
```

Its returned:

```
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I try to search for this trouble but this is didn't give me results.
I really hope that some kind person will be able to help me with this problem since I have been struggling with this for a couple of days.

Comment: When ever you see that level of nesting (anything beyond 3 deep) that is an indication your logic needs a re-think and code needs re-organising.

Comment: I understand this but have no idea how to change these iterations.

Comment: What can I change this cycle to?

Comment: Hi I think you mean ‘scrape’ and ‘scraping’. Scrap and scrapping mean throwing away, discarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write to use a single loop of a parent element collection. Choose a parent that encompasses all the data you want as blocks; 1 block per product; then, select relationally from that block within the loop to get the items within each block.

I have assumed id is product SKU.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

newItemList = []
base = 'https://www.nickollsandperks.co.uk/'

r = requests.get('https://www.nickollsandperks.co.uk/New-and-Special-Offers/New-Whisky?order=relevance:asc')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for listing in soup.select('.facets-items-collection-view-cell-span12'):
    price = listing.select_one('.product-views-price') #price
    if not price is None: #not every listing has a price
        price = price.text
    else:
        price = np.NaN
        
    newItemList.append(
       {'name': listing.select_one('.facets-item-cell-list-name span').text,
        'link': base + listing.select_one('.facets-item-cell-list-name')['href'],
        'price': price, 
        'id': listing.select_one('.facets-item-cell-list')['data-sku']
       }
    )
```

Comment: Ohh thank you, but I can't put this df in the mongodb,  and I found links in facets-item-cell-list-right meta. I try to fix this in your version but have an error.

Comment: What format do you need it in? And what additional links are required? Is it not just the product page link? You want a list of dictionaries?

Comment: As a string, as I can see this output like a table.

Comment: Ok. I updated based on appending dicts to a list as in your question.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much, can you describe to me, why I can't execute print(newItemList['link'])
but in the code below I can do it

Comment: `newItemList['link']` shouldn't work in your code as that is dictionary syntax.

Comment: Hmm, so I can't grab and print only links from this list for example?
I am sorry for these stupids questions, I am not a dev.
thank you in advance

Comment: You could have done that with the dataframe before by subsetting on column. You can't pull an item from a python list by name AFAIK; you use indices.

Comment: If you want links use print(' '.join([i["link"] for i in newItemList])) , or replace the space with a delimiter of your choice for join\

Answer (score 1):

I realized it like a string in another site, but I had less nesting:

```
content3 = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(content3.text, 'html.parser')
    newItemList = []
    for products in soup3.find_all("li", {"class": 'product-item'}):
        for products_info in products.find_all("strong", {"class": "product-item-name"}):
            for name in products_info.find_all("a"):
                for productsPriceInfo in products.find_all("div", {"class": "price-box price-final_price"}):
                    for productsPriceInfoAdv in productsPriceInfo.find_all("span", {
                        "class": "price-wrapper price-including-tax"}):
                        for finalPrice in productsPriceInfoAdv.find_all("span", {"class": "price"}):
                            productNames = {}
                    productNames['name'] = name['title']
                    productNames['price'] = finalPrice.get_text()
                    productNames['link'] = name['href']
                    productNames['ID'] = productsPriceInfo['data-product-id']
                    # dict = {'names': name['title']}
                    newItemList.append(productNames)

    return newItemList
```

this returned string with format - name: "name", link:"link" etc.